# How to make camera smooth when following player

Tags: unity, c#

When my character moves through my cameras 'FollowPlayer' script, the background just looks really glitchy and bad Is there anyway to fix this?

This is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour {
    Transform bar;

    void Start() {
        bar = GameObject.Find("PlayerMovingBar").transform;
    }

    void Update() {
        transform.position = new Vector3(
            bar.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the symptoms of "really glitchy and bad" in more detail? It's not obvious from your code what might be going wrong. Including an animated gif or a link to a short video of the problem can often help remove ambiguity when describing visual/animation artifacts.

Comment: [Here is a really useful program](http://www.screentogif.com/) for taking short screen recordings, and saving them as gifs. Take a recording of the background, and post it so we can see what you mean by "glitchy". As @DMGregory points out, you also want to *describe* "glitchy", to make your question understandable.

Comment: You also want to have a look into "Smooth Follow"; you do not seem to be applying any smoothing, and thus, it *is* going to look odd. The default Unity packages contain an example script.

Comment: well basically if im stationary the backround looks fine but right when I move it looks like the backround is moving up and down rapidly. I just want it smoother so it doesnt move up and down

Answer (score 1):

Using Lerp will give a smooth following effect as @Hellium mentioned.
It's also recommended to use it in the `LateUpdate()` method.

See Unity documentation for that : [MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html)

Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

You may simply need to Lerp to the desired position :

```
public float followSpeed = 10 ; // Change the value here to have the desired result

void Update() {
    Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(bar.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp( transform.position, targetPosition, followSpeed * Time.deltaTime );
 }
```

Comment: when I add that to my script the pubic followspeed turns red and the follow speed in the other part of it

Comment: Yes, indeed, sorry, I have forgotten the type of the variable....

Comment: well I added that to the script and it still seems like the backround is jumping around and moving when I move

Comment: The problem may not come from the script then. Please, provide additional information about your problem (gif or video) and the setup of your scene.

Comment: The deltaTime correction you've applied is not correct for the exponential ease-in style of Lerp you're using, which can cause the scene to judder on a variable framerate. You can use [the formula for weight in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/141334/39518) to correct it.