# Java LERP but with whole pixel values

Tags: java, libgdx, lerp

I have a formula which returns a `Lerp` `Vector3` value in integers but the problem is it never reaches the desired target value. It's converting to pixel values first by multiplying by PPM which is `float` 32f.

```
private Vector3 lerp(final Vector3 source, final Vector3 target, float alpha) {
    Vector3 sourcePPM = new Vector3(source.x * PPM, source.y * PPM, 0);
    Vector3 targetPPM = new Vector3(target.x * PPM, target.y * PPM, 0);
    sourcePPM.x += Math.round(alpha * (targetPPM.x - sourcePPM.x));
    sourcePPM.y += Math.round(alpha * (targetPPM.y - sourcePPM.y));
    source.x = sourcePPM.x / PPM;
    source.y = sourcePPM.y / PPM;
    source.z = 0;
    return source;
}
```

I initialize my vector variable `source` to `new Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`. Then, each frame I update it like this:

```
source = lerp(source, new Vector3(26.0, 29.0, 0.0), 0.06f);
```

But instead of eventually reaching the target, the value plateaus at a certain point:

```
Target destination: (26.0,29.0,0.0)
Actual final destination: (25.75,28.75,0.0)
```

Falling short of the target destination. If I don't round the values then it gets there fine but I need it to be in whole pixels.

The final line of intermediate values (too many to add all of them):

```
(25.0,27.90625,0.0)
(25.0625,27.96875,0.0)
(25.125,28.03125,0.0)
(25.1875,28.09375,0.0)
(25.25,28.15625,0.0)
(25.28125,28.21875,0.0)
(25.3125,28.28125,0.0)
(25.34375,28.3125,0.0)
(25.375,28.34375,0.0)
(25.40625,28.375,0.0)
(25.4375,28.40625,0.0)
(25.46875,28.4375,0.0)
(25.5,28.46875,0.0)
(25.53125,28.5,0.0)
(25.5625,28.53125,0.0)
(25.59375,28.5625,0.0)
(25.625,28.59375,0.0)
(25.65625,28.625,0.0)
(25.6875,28.65625,0.0)
(25.71875,28.6875,0.0)
(25.75,28.71875,0.0)
(25.75,28.75,0.0)
```

Comment: Somewhat tangentially, I think "Debugging with the scientific method" is an absolutely excellent talk. You may enjoy and benefit from watching it. It's at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FihU5JxmnBg

Comment: Here's a hypothesis: when source and target are sufficiently close to each other, `Math.round(alpha * (targetPPM.x - sourcePPM.x))` is zero, leading `source` to not be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Greek philosopher Zeno proposed a paradox: [an arrow can never strike its target](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Arrow_paradox_(Fletcher's_paradox)). In order to do so, it would have to:

- First, cross half the distance to its target.
- Then, cross half the remaining distance (one quarter of the original distance)
- Then, cross half *that* remaining distance (one eighth of the original)
- Then, cross half of ***that*** remaining distance (one sixteenth of the original)
- Then...

Because we can continue taking halves forever, this means there's an infinite number of steps the arrow has to take to reach the target. How could we ever perform infinite actions in finite time?

The solution to Zeno's paradox is the (apparently) continuous nature of time and space. Because each of these steps takes less and less time, while still making tiny increments of progress, we can show with calculus that the sum of all these infinite steps really does take only a finite amount of time, and summing all those infinite infinitesimals really does bring us all the way to our target.

Why does this matter? Because when you use this pattern for `lerp`:

```
current (variable) = lerp(current (variable), target (fixed), alpha (fixed));
```

Instead of this one:

```
current (variable) = lerp(start (fixed), end (fixed), progress (variable));
```

You're saying "I want my object to move like Zeno's arrow" - what we call an ["exponential ease-out" motion](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/149106/39518), or ["exponential moving average"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/141334/39518) if the target can change mid-flight.

The amount your `current` variable changes each frame is proportional to *how far it still has to go*:

- In your first call, when `current` is a long way from `target`, that difference is large, and `alpha` times that distance is proportionately large, so your `current` variable changes a lot.
- But as `current` gets closer and closer to `target`, the difference gets less and less, so `alpha` times that distance is proportionately smaller, and your `current` variable starts moving more slowly.

Now, because space *isn't* very continuous in your game - it's rounded to discrete pixels - there comes a point where the difference between `current` and `target` is so small that after multiplying by `alpha`, it rounds to zero. The arrow never reaches its target, and Zeno is right! (For a different reason than he had in mind though).

So, some potential solutions:

1. Let your underlying vector in the feedback loop stay unrounded, but then save its rounded value to another variable you use for your simulation/display:

```
   unroundedPosition = unroundedLerp(unroundedPosition, target, alpha);
   roundedPosition = Round(unroundedPosition * PPM)/PPM;

   // Use `roundedPosition` for anything that reads this object's position.
```

2. Detect the case where you round to zero, and fudge it to avoid getting stuck:

```
    private Vector3 roundedLerp(final Vector3 source, final Vector3 target, float alpha) {
        Vector3 sourcePPM = new Vector3(source.x * PPM, source.y * PPM, 0);
        Vector3 targetPPM = new Vector3(target.x * PPM, target.y * PPM, 0);

        float deltaX = (targetPPM.x - sourcePPM.x);
        // If we can make a whole pixel of progress with alpha, proceed as normal.
        if(Math.abs(alpha * deltaX) > 0.5) {
            sourcePPM.x += Math.round(alpha * deltaX);            
        // Otherwise, if we're more than half a pixel from our target, advance one pixel.
        } else if(Mathf.abs(deltaX) > 0.5) {
            sourcePPM.x += Math.signum(deltaX);
        } 

        float deltaY = (targetPPM.y - sourcePPM.y);
        if(Math.abs(alpha * deltaY) > 0.5) {
            sourcePPM.y += Math.round(alpha * deltaY);            
        } else if(Mathf.abs(deltaY) > 0.5) {
            sourcePPM.y += Math.signum(deltaY);
        } 

        source.x = sourcePPM.x / PPM;
        source.y = sourcePPM.y / PPM;
        source.z = 0;
        return source;
    }
```

3. Use the non-exponential form of `lerp`, and add any easing you want yourself:

```
    // Store a progress variable that goes from zero to 1 over your desired movement.
    progress = Math.Min(progress + deltaTime/transitionDuration, 1);

    // This gives you a quadratic ease-out: fast at the start, slow at the finish.
    float easeOut = 1 - (1 - progress) * (1 - progress);

    currentPosition = roundedLerp(startPosition, endPosition, easeOut);
```

Comment: You came back after all, that's great. Looks like we probably have the solution here. Your fudge formula does work although it's rather a big jump to get to the final destination at the end. It goes from (25.75,28.71875,0.0) to (26.0,28.75,0.0). In PPM terms that's quite a big jump.

Comment: For a lesser fudge, you can try the edited version, which advances one pixel at a time once it's so close that rounding the multiple of alpha drops to zero.

Comment: ♦ Ok I'll take a look at it. In any case in the meantime I was using the first solution which works fine too.

Comment: The first solution is definitely a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do and think about in your shoes:

- Print all the intermediate values. That might show you where the problem lies. If any value is not as expected, change your mental model (this may require research) such that your new model agrees with what you observed.
- My first guess about how to do this is to convert your given data to floats, calculate the lerp with floats, then convert the final result back to integers by rounding to nearest.
- Does `Math.round` round down, up, towards zero, to nearest integer? Make sure it does what you expect.

I can perhaps give a better answer if you print all the intermediate values and expand your question around the first value that surprises you. Note: You haven't showed us the `Vector3` constructor nor the type and precise value of `PPM` (is it `32.0`? Float or double?). Those might be helpful too.

Comment: I think this would be better suited as a comment since they are suggestions. I already tried it with floats and then rounding to integers, it has the same result. PPM if float 32f. I'll update my answer with that. I added some intermediate values, but not all since there are way too many.

Comment: I see that I was unclear: by intermediate I didn't mean "various different values of alpha", which is what I think you did. What I meant was printing the values of all the subexpressions. For example, printing `sourcePPM.x` before and after you've mutated it (with the highest value of alpha you give your function), and `sourcePPM.y`, and printing the value of the `Math.round(...)` expression, and printing `source.x` after you've set it, and so on.

Comment: Interestingly, with `Math.ceil` it finds it's destination, as long as x and y target values are positive values...if not it's even further off than `Math.round`. `Math.floor` would no doubt have the opposite effect.

Comment: Are you saying you need all those values in my question or that I look at those values myself? I've already been looking at every possible value, before and after, I have a million print line commands for every different value which I comment and uncomment. The only progress I've made though was about the rounding after your suggestion, as I detailed in the comment above.

Comment: I recommend you look at all the printed values, for a _single_ call to `lerp`, and explain more clearly which of the values you're surprised by. But actually I think @DMGregory is closer to helping you find the problem.

Comment: I'm not surprised by any of the values? I guess it would work if I used Math.ceil and Math.floor alternately depending whether the destination distance was negative or positive. Doesn't seem ideal though. DMGregory hasn't said anything helpful unless I missed it? I thought he was about to say something helpful after he clarified that I was using Lerp correctly, but he hasn't come back with anything more yet.

Comment: A single call to Lerp yielded target 26.0, targetPPM 832.0 PPM values with Math.floor 49.0 Math.round 50.0 Math.ceil 50.0.

Comment: Btw I found an error with my question, it should not say integers, it's about whole pixel values. I'm actually using float values everywhere but the rounding is making sure that the PPM values are whole pixels...but I'm not actually using '`int` anywhere. I changed the title to reflect that.